# Apply a css style to another css style

Tags: wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I'am using Bootstrap over a Wordpress template. I want to change the style of the "more-link" class and I want to give it the style of the .btn bootstrap class.

as far as I know, my solutions are to either inject into wordpress theme a way to add ".btn" to the string:

```
class="more-link"
```

to get

```
class="btn btn-default more-link"
```

and I have no clue on how to do it, or reverse engineer the style of .btn and simply copy/paste it into a.more-link style.

Either way seems way too much complicated, so I was thinking if there is a way to "forward" a style over another, to make the

```
a.more-link
```

style act exactly like the

```
.btn .btn-default
```

from bootstrap.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: You could clone the CSS Style: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6416527/1654265

Comment: You don't need to "reverse engineer" anything. Just `right-click > inspect element` a bootstrap button in chrome. there really isn't that much css to duplicate. It would literally take a few seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery to do this. add this to your theme footer.php just before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
           jQuery('.more-link').addClass('btn btn-default');
    });
</script>
```